# Why is my symbolic link not linking, but creating a file inside the diretory I'm trying to link

Tags: docker, ubuntu, drupal, composer-php, command-line-interface

Im trying to do a proyect on Drupal using Docker and Composer. This is my docker-compose.yml

```
app:
   build: ./app/.
   volumes:
    - /home/username/practicas/docker_drupal/drupal_ensi:/var/www
   links:
    - db
   ports:
    - 86:80

db:
   image: mariadb:10.5.3
   volumes:
    - /home/username/practicas/docker_drupal/db:/var/lib/mysql
   environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    - MYSQL_USER=admin
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=drupalDb
```

This is where I create the Drupal project with composer.

```
~/practicas/docker_drupal$ docker exec -it docker_drupal_app_1 bash
root@11da03a5baab:/var/www/html# php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev some-dir --no-interaction
```

Then I move all the content of the `some-dir` directory to the `/var/www/` level

```
root@11da03a5baab:/var/www/html# ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 May 22 09:57 some-dir
root@11da03a5baab:/var/www/html# cd ..
root@11da03a5baab:/var/www# ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 22 09:56 html
root@11da03a5baab:/var/www# mv html/some-dir/* ./
root@11da03a5baab:/var/www# ls -l
total 396
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  18046 May 22 09:56 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   6451 May 22 09:56 README.md
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   2370 May 22 09:56 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 343241 May 22 09:57 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 May 22 09:56 drush
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 May 22 09:56 html
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    321 May 22 09:56 load.environment.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    481 May 22 09:56 phpunit.xml.dist
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 May 22 09:56 scripts
drwxr-xr-x 54 root root   4096 May 22 09:57 vendor
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root   4096 May 22 09:57 web
```

And then try to do the symbolic link between `web` and `html`. When the server tries to go to the html directory by default, it should redirect to the web directory, because there's where the Drupal project is. (I dont know if I should do this inside the container or outside, but I would assume it really doesnt matter since its mounted in the docker-composer.yml, right? I dont know anymore at this point).

Whenever I try do the `ln -s web/ html`, it just creates a file inside the html folder, it doesnt create the link :c

```
~/practicas/docker_drupal/drupal_ensi$ sudo ln -s web/ html
[sudo] password for yindazai: 
yindazai@yindazai-Predator-PH317-52:~/practicas/docker_drupal/drupal_ensi$ ls -l
total 396
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   2370 may 22 11:56 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 343241 may 22 11:57 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 may 22 11:56 drush
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 may 22 12:07 html
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  18046 may 22 11:56 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    321 may 22 11:56 load.environment.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    481 may 22 11:56 phpunit.xml.dist
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   6451 may 22 11:56 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 may 22 11:56 scripts
drwxr-xr-x 54 root root   4096 may 22 11:57 vendor
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root   4096 may 22 11:57 web

yindazai@yindazai-Predator-PH317-52:~/practicas/docker_drupal/drupal_ensi/html$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 may 22 11:58 some-dir
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    4 may 22 12:07 web -> web/
```

This last part was done outside the container, but if I do it inside, it doesnt create the link but a file inside the html folder.

I think I'am doing all the steps right, but obviously its not work, so any help would be indeed much appreciated. Thx.

Comment: Hey @Alonso wanted to understand why aren't you doing all these steps in your Dockerfile? You should create a Dockerfile for Drupal app and then create, copy directories and create symlinks in Dockerfile.

Comment: im new to Docker and all of its possibilities. The guy teaching me doesnt want us to build or dockerfiles just yet, he gave us one already filled. We just have to get drupal working with the composer inside the container

Comment: Well then you shouldn't learn from him :)

Assuming you have your Drupal project ready and working on your local machine, you jest need couple of commands in Dockerfile to setup and run your project. Like MKDIR, COPY, RUN and then include the Dockerfile in compose. Ask your tutor if you need to build 10+(let's say 'n') containers, would you be doing all these 'n' number of times? What's the use of using Docker. Sorry I went off topic, but yeah you should start with Dockerfile.

Comment: He gave us the Dockerfile because that is how they work in their company, he just wants for all of us to have the same stuff and such. Im gonna try to erase the html directory in var/www. After what ive searched, when you do ln -s firstDirectory secondDirectory, you are creating the second directory, see if that works

Comment: yeah, it was simple as that. That did the trick and can know install drupal from localhost ^^ thx for the tips in dockerfile though, ill sure practice them. They seem like too much for know because i dont really know what i need or dont need to RUN and other requirements.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can have a little help at github: https://github.com/wayoflegend/drupalindocker  . Because in fact you have a little  miss understand of the composer commands and may be you didn't have the right vhost configuration.

Comment: Thx, I'll defenitely check it out c: Indeed im new to docker and drupal as well and may have confused and confusion on some things.